# How to detect missing tick() in fakeAsync()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, race-condition, zone.js

I wrote this test for my Angular app:

```
it('should request confirmation before deleting & abort action if user declined', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(appService, 'confirm').and.returnValue(of(false));
    spyOn(personService, 'delete').and.callThrough();
    component.deleteEntry(testPerson);
    //tick(); // Missing tick()!
    expect(personService.delete).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

This is the component method I'm testing:

```
async deleteEntry(person: Person) {
    if (await this.appService.confirm().toPromise()) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        await this.personService.delete(person).toPromise();
    } catch(resp) {
        this.appService.errorMsgBox();
    }
}
```

(`confirm()`'s purpose is to show a confirmation dialog and return an Observable emitting `true` / `false` depending on the user input)

If you look carefully, there is an error in my component function. I forget the `!`-operator when checking the result of `confirm()`. The correct code would be

```
    if (!await this.appService.confirm().toPromise()) {
```

However, the test will pass. I'm not 100% sure, but I guess it passes, because the `expect()`-statement at the end performs its check before `confirm()` has returned its value. So yes, of course, `personService.delete()` has not been called. If I uncomment the `tick()` the test works as expected, and detects the error.

Now I expected `fakeAsync()` to throw an error due to pending microtasks. To my suprise, it does not. The test passes without any errors or warnings, although [the docs say](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync):

> If there are any pending timers at the end of the function, an exception will be thrown.

So it seems we have a race condition here, i.e. `confirm()` is resolved before returning `fakeAsync()` but after `expect()`. If this is possible, what is the deal about `fakeAsync()`, if not controlling those things?

Probably I and other developers will forget `tick()` or `flushMicrotasks()` in future as well. So I wonder, how to avoid this. Is there some kind of helper function I'm missing that I can put in `afterEach()`? Or is the behavior of `fakeAsync()` an Angular bug, i.e. it should throw an exception?

**EDIT**

See a full working example of my problem on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnmubr. Notice that you have to click the 'refresh'-button of the inner browser view (next to the editor) if you want to re-run the test or after you changed something. The auto-reload feature will not work and throw errors.

I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1135), like someone suggested in the comments.

Comment: Does `this.appService.confirm().toPromise()` return an observable or a value? I see that the spy mocks its returnValue to be an observable _i.e._ `of(false)`. AFAIK, that should be truthy

Comment: `confirm()` returns an observable which emits `true` if the user confirms the action and `false` otherwise. `toPromise()` converts the Observable to a Promise, i.e. subscribes and resolves the returned promise with the first value received from the Observable. `of(false)` simulates the user declining the action (Pressing the "no" button of the confirmation dialog)

Comment: Oh, thanks. That makes sense to me now. I'm guessing that you can favor `async` wrapper over the `fakeAsync` and write your expectations as a `microtask`. The `tick` causes a wait for the `confirm` promise to be resolved.

Comment: @fishbone, could you post a reproduce repo? Or post an issue here, https://github.com/angular/zone.js, I will check it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your tests are at least written the same way, one or the other should fail if a `tick` is missing / wrong.  It isn't perfect, but you could try moving your test logic into a common function so that you have some degree of confidence that it does what you meant:

```
function callDelete() {
    spyOn(personService, 'delete').and.callThrough();
    component.deleteEntry(testPerson);
    //tick(); // Missing tick()!
}

it('aborts delete if user declined', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(appService, 'confirm').and.returnValue(of(false));
    callDelete();
    expect(personService.delete).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
}));

it('deletes if user accepted', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(appService, 'confirm').and.returnValue(of(true));
    callDelete();
    expect(personService.delete).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Now, your second test will fail (because `expect` ran before the `await` resolved).  By debugging this, you'll either notice the logic error in your code under test, fix that, then find the test error. Or, you'll find and fix the test error, which will cause the first test to fail, and then find the logic error.  The only way you can miss it is if you `tick` wrong in one test but not the other (or fail to test all conditional branches).

Answer (score 0):

[This issue](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/1135) reveals that currently `fakeAsync()`doesn't throw an exception for pending micro tasks but only for pending timers. At the moment there seems to be no way to ensure there are no pending micro tasks at the end of the test. However, the developers are going to check if this is a feature.